# How do I create KnockoutJS computed observables where the view model isn't a function?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I can't work out how to access the other items in the view model from inside the anonymous [computed function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). How do I get this/self/sys or a reference to the view model?

http://jsfiddle.net/2z66yxkz/

```
var sys = {

    viewModel: {

        first: ko.observable('John'),
        last: ko.observable('Doe'),
        name: ko.computed(function() {

            // this.first?
            // this.viewModel.first()?
            // sys.viewModel.first?

            console.log(this);
            return 'first + last';
        }),
    }
};


$(function() {

    ko.applyBindings(sys.viewModel, $('#cont')[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way the objects are laid out, and how knockout runs the functions you provide to the computeds, you don't currently easily have access to those properties.  You can instead alter your layout a little to use IIFEs to create instances of objects:

```
var sys = new (function(){
    this.viewModel = new (function() {
        this.first = ko.observable('John');
        this.last = ko.observable('Doe');
        this.name = ko.computed(function() {
            return this.first() + ' ' + this.last();
        }, this); //Note "this" - see below
    })();
})();
```

Knockout computeds take a second argument to specify what the value of `this` should be when running.  With the viewmodel rewritten in this fashion, we can pass the current object in as the `this` parameter for the computed callback to use.

Here's [an update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z66yxkz/1/).

Comment: That looks like a hack though.

Comment: It's far from a hack - personally I'd much prefer objects laid out in this fashion as it adds an extra scope where you can hide away internals if needed.

Comment: @Person Take a look [at this knockout example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) - it's pretty much the same as what is here, other than the fact that you've got an extra object (`sys`) containing `viewModel`, and I'm constructing it inline as opposed to at the time of passing it to `ko.applyBindings`

Comment: @Person That's fine.  I made it a function mostly through force of habit :)  As mentioned earlier, it would allow for locally scoped variables within just that function if necessary at a later date etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your `computed` observable outside of the view model object literal, like this:

```
var viewModel: {
    first: ko.observable('John'),
    last: ko.observable('Doe')
};

viewModel.name = ko.computed(function() {
    // Now you can reference first and last values through 
    // the viewModel variable, like this:
    return viewModel.first() +  " " + viewModel.last();
}),
```

Comment: Note that you can't do this inline as per the OP - you'd have to create the variable then create/assign it to `sys` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a constructor for that one, like this

```
sys = function() {
    var self = {};
    self.first = ko.observable('John');
    self.last = ko.observable('Snow');
    self.Name = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.first + self.last;
    });
    return {
        viewModel:self
    };
}();


$(function () {

    ko.applyBindings(sys.viewModel, $('#cont')[0]);
});
```

Please note the parenthesis after the function declaration. That make the function self apply, giving you the instance.